# Why String.toDouble() will increase decimal places?

Tags: kotlin

I have a server returning a value (in JSON) which contains a number with decimal places, e.g. `203.14`.

Since in my app I need to do some calculation, I have to convert it to `Double`.

However when it is converted to Double, it's value becomes `203.13999938964844`.

For some business logic reason, when I display this value, I need to round **down** this number to 2 decimal places.

So now it becomes `203.13`, which is 0.01 smaller than the value server returns.

How can I preserve `203.14` when I convert `"203.14"` to Double?

### Update:

I just found that the reason is because the model class used `float` to accept the server value, but then later converted to `Double`. If day one the model class uses `double` to accept the value, then the problem above will not exist.

Comment: Why doues rounding that value yield a smaller number? The given double value will only be rounded to `203.13` if you round down instead of arithmetic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: If you want precise floating point calculations, use a `BigDecimal`. If you just want to fix the display problem, round instead of truncating.

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes I have to round it down.

Comment: Regarding your update: changing from float to double might fix the issue for this specific value, but it won't for all numbers. Doubles give you double the precision, but not absolute precision.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this rounding method after initializing the Double:

```
fun Double.round(decimals: Int): Double {
    var multiplier = 1.0
    repeat(decimals) { multiplier *= 10 }
    return round(this * multiplier) / multiplier
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
3.14159265359.round(2)
```

Answer (score -1):

It appears to me that the number's real value is 203.1399999999999, but when you are outputting the data, the String format is rounding it to 203.14. If this is the case, then try to round the number before converting it to a Double.

If that doesn't work, try using either of the following methods instead of the one that you are currently using:
Double.parseDouble()
Double.valueOf()

Comment: No, the value server returns is `203.14` exactly.

Comment: What method are you using to convert 203.14 to a double?

Comment: @SiraLam there's no way to represent 203.14 exactly in binary floating-point

Comment: @SiraLam `value server returns is 203.14 exactly` No, because `203.14` does not have an exact (terminating) representation in the [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) floating point format that `double` uses.